# Guid does not get transferred to service correctly using ASP.NET Core web service

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nsjsonserialization

I have the following problem: I have an `IDto` interface and a `Dto` base class implementing said interface.

The base class overrides an `id` and a `ManualId` which are defined in the `HasId` base class.

Then I also have an `AuthorDto` which inherits from the `Dto` base class.

Now when I try to perform a http request (`POST` method) to the service, the `ManualId` does not get transferred to the service correctly even though the JSON string contains the correct `ManualId`.

Please help.

My IDto interface:

```
public interface IDto : IHasId 
{
    IDto CloneData();
}
```

My dto base class:

```
public abstract class Dto : HasId, IDto 
{
    [DataMember]
    public override long? Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public override Guid ManualId { get; protected set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public abstract IDto CloneData();

    protected bool Equals(Dto other) 
    {
        return base.Equals(other) && Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if(ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if(obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        return Equals((Dto)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        unchecked 
        {
            return(base.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

The `HasId` class:

```
public abstract class HasId : IHasId 
{
    public abstract long? Id { get; set; }
    public abstract Guid ManualId { get; protected set; }

    protected bool Equals(HasId other) 
    {
        return Id == other.Id && ManualId.Equals(other.ManualId);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if(ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if(obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        return Equals((HasId) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        unchecked 
        {
            return(Id.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ ManualId.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

The class doing the HttpRequest:

```
public class HttpHelper 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client = new();

    public async Task<TResult> GetObject<TResult>(string requestUri) 
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var valueInJsonFormat = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(valueInJsonFormat);
    }

    public async Task<TResult> PostObject<T, TResult>(T obj, string requestUri) 
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri(requestUri), data);

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) 
        {
            var httpContent =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpResponseContent>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            try 
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                throw new Exception(httpContent?.Detail ?? e.Message, e);
            }
        }

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(result);
    }
}
```

This is the JSON-String:

```
[
{"Author":
  {
    "Id":1,
    "Settings":
      {
        "Id":1,
        "ArchiveXml":false,
        "CreatePdfImmediately":false,
        "OverwriteExistingXml":false,
        "SaveSimilarTopic":false,
        "PdfNameTemplate":null,"PdfPath":null, 
        "ManualId":"624fa6e3-0864-40bf-87c3a7fcaa1421d4"
      }, 
    "Name":"Admindef", 
    "IsAdmin":true,
    "PublicKey" : PUBLIC-KEY HERE (removed since its not relevant),
    "ManualId":"f15cb1a5-2d66-4ca9-8dc6-1bf5c25bc7f8"},"Operation":0}]
```

Comment: Hi, please provide some code or a minimal reproducible example, for example, you can provide code for the mentioned classes and the JSON you are trying to send to your service. Also, how you are "transferring" the data? Is it a POST request?

Comment: I did so @MarkiianBenovskyi

Comment: Thanks, could you also post an example JSON string?

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi I did. When you try solving it, please look at the exisitng answer and my comment to it so you know what problem still exists. Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are trying to `POST` a `JSON` string with a `ManualId` in it, but in the service, you don't get the same `ManualId` as in your `json`.

I think the problem is that your method to `set` the `ManualId` is `protected`.

See here:

```
public abstract Guid ManualId { get; protected set; }
```

Protecting it means it won't be `set` from the deserialisation.

You should use the default get and set pair like here:

```
public abstract Guid ManualId { get; set; }
```

See if this fixes your issue?

This change can also be related to your `Dto` class and your `HasId` class.

---

If you want to be able to set the property from the JSON but keep it protected in the code, then you should create a constructor with the parameters you want to deserialize.

Deserialisation follows the following principle:

[image: JSON deserialisation]

And you need to be sure that in this graph you will end up calling a constructor with parseable parameters.

Comment: Yeah this has solved my issue but with that change i am facing another. See the protected set is there to make sure the ManualId can not be changed outside the class its being defined or its deriving classes. So when i remove that you can set the Manualid from anywhere